# Facebook graph API search in group feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

According to Facebook graph API playground it is possible to search in a page/group feed ,
I'm using the following URL to do so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<group_id>/feed?q=<search query>&access_token=<access_token>
```

And this is the result i'm getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "FVaffSuGwvg"
  }
}
```

What is the problem here ?

Comment: No, it is not possible to search in feeds. (I assume by API playground you mean the Graph API Explorer? Just because that might suggest a certain syntax, does not necessarily mean it must exist.)

Comment: @CBroe is right. One thing you can do is to retrieve group feed from the API and then perform search at your end.